# tfs 2012 error TF400534

Tags: installation

I am trying to install TFS 2012 RC and while is copying files showed the below error:

```
"Error: TF400534 : Package (tfs_servercoreres_x64) caching failed"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error and fixed it reinstalling tfs express.  My installer was corrupted. So, Re-download it from Microsoft official site here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#tfs

Also, remember that The user account to install it should be a member of the Administrators group.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to my blog [link](http://bharathtechupdate.blogspot.com/2012/07/Configuring-TFS-2012-on-Windows-2012.html) below for Installing and Configuring (TFS) Team Foundation Server 2012 RC on Windows Server 2012 RC with SQL Server 2012 RC.

http://bharathtechupdate.blogspot.com/2012/07/Configuring-TFS-2012-on-Windows-2012.html

I am having a VM image in that i have ADMINISTRATOR account on which i executed this setup process and configured TFS 2012 to work with SharePoint Server 2013 preview.

Hope the blog post helps for you or let me know in case of any issues/clarifications.